# Watching for file changes does nothing when containing directory deleted

Tags: gulp

Consider this task:

```
gulp.task("WatchDirectoryForAllFileChanges", function () {
    gulp.watch("Build/**/*",
        function (event) {
            console.log("event", event);
        });
});
```

When I add or remove individual files in the *Build* directory I get events as expected. But when I delete a directory containing files I get no events at all for the removal of the files within that directory.

Is there an explanation for this behavior, and is it possible to handle it properly? I'd think directory deletion like this is a common enough scenario to motivate some befuddlement here.

Answer (score 0):

While this is not an answer why gulp behaves like this, I found [chokidar](https://github.com/paulmillr/chokidar) which handles this stuff correctly:

```
var chokidar = require("chokidar");
gulp.task("Watch", function () {
    return chokidar.watch("Build/**", { ignoreInitial: true })
        .on("all", function (event, path) {
            console.log(event, path);
        });
});
```